# Is a question like "is this [self-made graphic] correct/spot the errors [in said graphic]" acceptable?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

If I were to create something analgous to [xkcd's Movie Narrative Chart](http://xkcd.com/657/) for some other story, would posting as a question to ask 'is this correct' appropriate?

I could see it being closed as being *too-localized* as presumably I'd be the only one that cares about it, but the ultimate ends of the question would be more expansive.

Answer (score 3):

It might be marginally on-topic but is at risk of:

- having too many answers if there are errors
- ALL of which become localizedly wrong once you correct those errors.

For the latter reason, I'd strongly recommend posting in chat instead.